# When inserting an element with the html method can I keep the original in the DOM?

Tags: jquery

I found a strange thing. When I insert an element into another with the jQuery `html()` method, the first element is removed from DOM. I want to know if it is possible to insert an element and keep it in DOM.

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqueE/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    select1 = $("#select-1");
    select2 = $("#select-2");
    $("#gap").html(select2); //Original select2 removed from DOM
});
```

As you can see the `#select-2` element is no longer visible if it is inserted into another element. But I want to insert it, and keep the priginal element as before.

Comment: Are you asking why "#select-2" is is removed from it's position in the DOM and moved into "#gap", instead of a COPY of "#select-2" being moved?

Comment: @Cranio and TheC0d3r - The OP is expecting to see *three* `select` elements. You should only be able to see 2.

Comment: This is basically a duplicate of [How to append one jQuery element already in the DOM to another element?](/q/6364633/4642212), but it is a strange special case; strange because the behavior of `.html(jQueryObject)` doesn’t appear to be [documented](//api.jquery.com/html), so it’s questionable whether this even _should_ work the way it does. It is, at least, mentioned in [issue #1109](//github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/1109).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your question correctly, you can [`clone`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) the element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var select1 = $("#select-1"),
        select2 = $("#select-2");
    $("#gap").html(select2.clone());
});
```

If you need to keep any event handlers that were bound to `select2` you can pass `true` as an argument to `clone`.

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/aqueE/2/).

---

As a side note, notice that I've added the `var` keyword before your variable declarations. This prevents the variables from leaking into the global scope (which you usually don't want).

---

As another side note, it looks like this form of the `html` method is not documented in the jQuery API (it lists `.html( htmlString )`, and states that `htmlString` should be a "string of HTML").

The [jQuery source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/manipulation.js#L211) however, clearly allows the use of a string, an element or a jQuery object. If  `htmlString` is a string, the native `innerHTML` property is used. If not, the `append` method is used instead:

```
if ( typeof value === "string" /* ... */ ) {
    //...
}
if ( elem ) {
    this.empty().append( value ); //In your case we end up here
}
```

Comment: Add parameter true to clone() so it clones event handlers too

Comment: Oh sorry, either it wasn't there when I commented or I skipped that

Comment: Thanx, also another good method is "select2.clone().appendTo("#gap");"

Comment: @jumancy - You're welcome :) The difference with that example is that it will *append* the element, rather than replacing the contents with that element.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    select1 = $("#select-1");
    select2 = $("#select-2");
    $("#gap").html(select2.html());
    select1.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    select1 = $("#select-1");
    select2 = $("#select-2").html();
    $("#gap").html(select2);
    select1.show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
var select2 = $("#select-2");
```

you are directly referring to the DOM-Element, not just it's content! That's why you move the element instead of cloning it.

To do the latter either write:

```
$("#gap").html(select2.clone());
```

or

```
$("#gap").html(select2.html());
```

or

```
var select2 = $("#select-2").html();
$("#gap").html(select2);
```

Comment: html() is not correct, because it takes html code inside the element, not whole element

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are several commands to do this.
I usually use: insertAfter(), insertBefore(), before(), after(), append(), appendTo(), prepend(), prependTo().

Common way of using it:
**html**

```
<div id="somediv">
    some content
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("<span/>").html("this is what I'm appending").appendTo("#somediv");
});
```

Here I appended a span inline-block element to the existing div block.
The other functions are similar, feel free to read the documentation.

If you want to keep the original, just use clone before like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var theclone = $("#select-2").clone();
  theclone.appendTo("#gap");
});
```

Of course there are several ways to do this, but I think this gets the job done.
Here's your modified example: http://jsfiddle.net/9PAYd/